# Is it possible to scan an xml element using single Xpath expression when the element is case insensitive

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have below `XML` which I need to parse.I need to take name value.But the name element might be case insensitive.How to write a generic `Xpath` epression to read element with `name` or `Name`?

```
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <Name>Lisa</Name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Below expression will good for name element when we give `id` as dynamic value.

XPathExpression:

```
exprs = xpath.compile("/Employees/Employee/@id" + id+ "']/name/text()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below `XPath` to match both `name` and `Name` elements

```
/Employees/Employee/*[matches(name(), "name", "i")]/text()
```

`/*[matches(name(), "name", "i")]` should match any element (`*`) which name (`name()`) is equal to `"name"` ignoring (`"i"`) case

Answer (score 1):

You can try the XPath translate() function :

**translate(string1,string2,string3)**

Converts **string1** by replacing the characters in **string2** with the characters in **string3**

In your case, the following:

`//Employee/*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='name']";`

will:

1. For each `Employee`
2. Check each children
3. Convert all letter in the name of the child ( `local-name()` ) that are Uppercase to lowercase
4. Compare it to "name"

With this, you don't have to check manually for each possibility and can be re-use for anything else too ; you just have to replace "name" by tho word you want to check.

For futher reading:

translate()  --> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XPath/Fonctions/translate

local-name() --> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XPath/Fonctions/local-name